# How to mock a function which is being called by another function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am using Jest to unit test my modules. I have a module say `fooModule.ts`.
I have 3 functions inside `export const foo = () => {}, export const bar = () => {}, export const baz = () => {}`. Now the function `foo()` internally calls bar and baz. Now these two methods are what I want to mock to give different results to foo. How do I proceed forward with this?

I tried using `mockImplementation`, but later I found out that made no sense.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60992696/6463558 answer your question?

Comment: Can I use sinon to make stubs which work with jest too? And the fact that I'm using typescript, wont make a difference right?

Comment: You don't need to use sinonjs. jestjs is enough. channge `export const xx` to `exports.xx= xx`. And in your `foo` function, change `bar()` and `baz()` to `exports.bar()`, `exports.baz()`. Then, you can use `jest.spyOn` spy or mock them.